# What is the concept of Kendra & Trikona in a Kundali (horoscope birth chart)?

Tags: scripture, astrology, navagraha

##### Several times when we visit a Jyotiṣhī āchārya, they frequently mention the words "Kendra" & "Trikoṇa", while discussing our *janma-patrikā* Kuṇḍalī.

For instance, the most fear inciting statement one can hear might be -

> यजमान, आपके केंद्र में तो शनि, नीच के बैठे हैं। जीवन में बहुत कठिनाइयाँ हैं।
>  ईश्वर की नित्य उपासना करें ।
>
> yajamāna, āpake kendra mein to Śhani, nīcha ke baiṭhe haiṃ.  jīvana meṃ bahuta kaṭhināiyām̐ haiṃ.
>  īśvara kī nitya upāsanā kareṃ.
>
> > O Dear! the *kendra* in your chart is occupied by Śhani (Saturn) at its worst. Your life looks filled with hardships.
> >  You must worship the Lord daily.

Further,

> आपका त्रिकोण अच्छा है, चिंता की कोई आवश्यकता नही है।
>
> āpakā trikoṇa acchā hai, ciṃtā kī koī āvaśyakatā nahī hai.
>
> > Your *trikoṇa* is well placed, no need to worry.

---

#### Question -

##### So, I want to know about this concept of "Kendra" & "Trikoṇa" in detail.
 How much important they are and why? Please give answers derived from the relevant authoritative scriptures.

Comment: Kendra refers to the 1st, 4th, 7th and 10th house in ones Chart. Trikona means the 1st, 5th and 9th. Any planet placed in these will give good/ neutral effects as per whatever they give.

Comment: Trikona(1,5,9) are Dharma houses and base of Artha, Kama, Moksha. Jupiter in Trikona with its (1,5,9) aspect can counter all horoscope doshas and promises everything necessary in life. House 1 of Lagna is person's head and his/her body inherits the nature of God of ascendant nakshatra(also of rashi nakshatra God). Kendra(1) controls Self, Kendra(4) controls mother/home, Kendra(7) controls wife and job(as its bhavat bhavam of 10th) and Kendra(10) controls father/profession. Kendra & Trikona planet lords also form benefic yogakaraka planet.Same thing for Moon(mind) chart should be also seen

Comment: @Vivikta I was member of site from 2018 and gained around 2000 reputation points till mid 2020 and regular upvoter, writer of answers and contemporary to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3869/srimannarayana-k-v . After conflicts with some sectarian members on this site, I deleted my account. I had been writing comments on this site again since 2021 with my new account on some questions based on my research and revelations(in 2020) on Vedanta, Vedic Astrology and Vastu but for some time and to help few real seekers of Hinduism and its core truth.

Comment: No problem, @Manu Kumar , it was just a suggestion. However, I'd give one further suggestion: Please don't be perturbed by sectarian nonsense here, that's a part and parcel. Just ignore it as much as possible (be like the Majestic Elephant to the wolves rant). I'd still suggest that you'd be more active in here. :))

Answer (score 1):

> The 8th, the 6th and the 12th houses are known as Dusthanas or houses of evil. The rest are termed good houses and will be propitious to the native. **The 1st, the 10th, the 7th and the 4th houses are known by the terms Kendra**, Kantaka, and Chatushtaya.- *Phaladeepika by Mantreswara, Chapter 1, Verse 17*.

> The houses next to the Kendras, i.e., the 2nd, the 5th, the 8th and the 11th are known as Panaphara. The 3rd, the 6th, the 9th and the 12th are Apoklima houses. The 4th and the 8th are designated Chaturasra houses. The 10th, 3rd, the 6th and the 11th houses are called Upachaya; **the 9th and the 5th are known as Trikona houses and these are auspicious.** - *Phaladeepika by Mantreswara, Chapter 1, Verse 18*.

I just want to add a couple of things.

- Phaladeepika is arguably the second most important classic in Parasara school. Mantreswara himself was an ardent follower of the Parasari principles.
- You have to count houses from the Lagna and in a counter-clockwise fashion in a North Indian birth chart.

Reference:

1. Mantreswara's Phaladeepika with an English Translation by Panditabhushana V. Subrahamanya Sastri, 2nd Edition, 1950